# Mysql trouble with Case , then and when

Tags: mysql

I am maintaining a database with minimum 100 rows. An ajax call is made every 10 secs to update the rows. I feel that it would be not advisable to Call 100 times update query every 10 secs. So i came across mysql case,then and when, to combine 100 queries to one single query and do the update. But i am having trouble with the code. Here's my code with two rows

```
update customer_details set (date,customer_name,school_name,mobile_number,customer_email,age,area,customer_requirement,extra_comments,draft_message) = 
 case `id`
when '275' then ('09-04-201','person1','','1234567890','','','','basketball','','message')
when '274' then  ( '','','','','','','area','xyz','','message')
end
```

and the error is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(date,customer_name,school_name,mobile_number,customer_email,age,area,customer_r' at line 1
```

I am unable to rectify the error. And also is there any other method to make a single query call for 100 rows?

Comment: You could write a complex query to update all 100 rows at once, but it would be awkward - and would make maintenance difficult. If you do 100 separate normal Update queries that would be cleaner; and unless your database server is under-powered, 100 updates every ten seconds shouldn't lead to performance problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried:

```
INSERT INTO customer_details (id, date,customer_name,school_name,mobile_number,customer_email,age,area,customer_requirement,extra_comments,draft_message) VALUES
(275, '09-04-201','person1','','1234567890','','','','basketball','','message'),
(274, '','','','','','','area','xyz','','message')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
date=VALUES(date),
customer_name=VALUES(customer_name),
school_name=VALUES(school_name),
mobile_number=VALUES(mobile_number),
customer_email=VALUES(customer_email),
age=VALUES(age),
area=VALUES(area),
customer_requirement=VALUES(customer_requirement),
extra_comments=VALUES(extra_comments),
draft_message=VALUES(draft_message);
```

Comment: tried it but its not updating or replacing due to foreign key constraint. the error displayed `#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (backend.customer_sms, CONSTRAINT customer_sms_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer_details (id))`

Comment: You said nothing abou `FK` in your question. Now you must to use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` syntax. I'm updated my answer one more time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set each column in a set statement, the syntax is:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = "value1", column2 = "value2" ....
WHERE IdDColumn = MyID
```

In your case your will have two options:

```
UPDATE tablename SET Column1 =  
CASE
  WHEN id = 275 THEN Value1
  WHEN id = 274 THEN Value2
  ELSE DefaultValue 
END, Column2 =  
CASE
  WHEN id = 275 THEN Value1
  WHEN id = 274 THEN Value2
  ELSE DefaultValue  
END,
etc...
```

Comment: ok. but what about multiple values corresponding to specific id?

Comment: Add a where id = YourId at the end

Comment: UPDATE tablename SET column1 = "value1", column2 = "value2" where id=1 and UPDATE tablename SET column1 = "value1", column2 = "value2" where id=2
will this work?

Comment: thanks.. I got my solution as suggested by Arthur Halma. i shall try out your's also.